# Why is it more efficient to define operator+ to call operator+= rather than the other way around?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

It's an exercise from *C++ Primer 5th Edition*:

> Exercise 14.14: Why do you think it is more efficient to define
>   operator+ to call operator+= rather than the other way around?(P.561)

Given the implementations for `operator+=` and `operator+`:

```
Sales_data& 
Sales_data::operator+=(const Sales_data &rhs)
{
    units_sold += rhs.units_sold;
    revenue += rhs.revenue;
    return *this;
}

Sales_data
operator+(const Sales_data &lhs, const Sales_data &rhs)
{
    Sales_data sum = lhs;  // copy data members from lhs into sum
    sum += rhs;             // add rhs into sum
    return sum;
}
```

At the end of this section (14.3) , the author gave a tip that

> Classes that define both an arithmetic operator and the related
>   compound assignment ordinarily ought to implement the arithmetic
>   operator by using the compound assignment.

Can anyone explain this tip, using facts/examples?

Comment: Usually `operator+` returns a new value, where `operator+=` modifies one object. After all, you don't expect `a` or `b` to change in `a + b + c`. This implicates that `+=` uses a temporary value. However, if you have `+=`, you can simply take the first argument in your `operator+` by value instead of reference and make your function really small: `return left_hand_side += right_hand_side;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`operator+=` would use an unnecessary temporary object if it were implemented using `operator+`, as you can see in the first line of the `operator+` example.

Answer (score 10):

The reason is in the number of copying that needs to be made: binary operator `+` creates and returns a new object that represents a sum, while the compound addition-assignment operator modifies the object in place.

If you would like to implement the compound operator in terms of the binary operator, the sequence of actions would be as follows:

- Compound assignment calls the binary operator
- The binary operator creates a new object from one of the objects (copy #1),  and puts the sum into it
- The sum is returned by value (copy #2)
- The sum object is copied into the object on the left-hand side object (copy #3)

If you do it the other way around, the last copy is eliminated:

- Binary operator creates an object representing the sum from the left-hand side object
- Binary operator invokes the compound addition-assignment, which does not require copying
- Binary operator returns the object by value (copy #2)

Therefore, using the compound addition-assignment in the implementation of the binary `+` is more efficient.